# Ruby on Rails - Add & Remove record from table when click twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, controller

In my application I've a button called *Interested*. When this button is clicked it'll add a record to `interests` table with `user_id` & `post_id`.

*This is My `PostsController`:*

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def interested
    @interest = Interest.new
    @interest.user_id = params[:user_id]
    @interest.post_id = params[:post_id]
    @interest.save
  end
```

*My `routes.rb`*

```
get 'i/:user_id/:post_id', to: 'posts#interested', as: :interested
```

*My show view:*

```
= link_to "Interested", interested_path(post.id, current_user), remote: true
```

How can I make it so when it's clicked it adds the record to my table & if clicked twice, it removes the record from table *(as if they are not interested anymore)*

Comment: Hello @Cyzanfar I still have not added the remove function yet, since I use `remote: true` for `link_to`. Yeah I've though of `find_or_create_by` and will implement after I've the *add* & *remove* function.

Comment: Don't get your first sentence...

Comment: You asked: *Are you sure it removes it from the table ?* and I said: I still have not added the remove function yet. If I understood correctly what you meant

Comment: Ok so basically removes the record if it exists already correct ?

Comment: Yeah, with the same `link_to` button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood, the first time a user clicks "interested" on a post you want to save that as a post the user is interested in. However when the user clicks "interested" once again on a post he already marked as interested then you want to delete the record.

This is one way to achieve that:

```
def interested
 @interested = Interest.find_by(user_id: params[:user_id], post_id: params[:post_id]
 if @interested
  @interested.destroy
 else
   Interest.create(user_id: params[:user_id], post_id: params[:post_id])
 end
end
```

You'd also want some sort of flash message to indicate that the interest has successfully been created/destroyed

Answer (score 0):

You could have 2 link_to buttons, one for "interested" and one hidden for "not interested". The 2 buttons could go to their own action in the controller: interested-action and a not_interested-action. Then you get a nice seperation of concerns in handling the database part of things. The 2 buttons are of course toggled in javascript/jquery in click event handlers using show/hide method.

In the interested-action on the server you should use the find_or_create_by method to get hold of the record. Then on the record should be a field "active" set to true determining whether the user is interested. In the not_interested-action this field is simply set to false.

Comment: The problem with your approach is that the record would be created either way if interested or not which is not necessarily a bad thing but for this particular use case it wouldn't make much sense since the absence of a interest record is an indication that the user hasn't expressed any interest  (yet).